# Generate full path of file names with .cpp, .hpp, .h, .c extension

Tags: perl, find

In perl, given two or more base directories, I need to find files of `.cpp`, `.hpp`, `.h`, `.c` extension and generate full path like Windows Find tool.

E.g., say
I have two or more base directories

```
C:\foo\bar\
C:\foo\bar\barbar
```

and I need to generate full path of `.cpp`, `.hpp`, `.h`, `.c` file names in given base directories.

Those files may exist in `C:\foo\bar\bar\foo\bar\foo\`, but I know only few base directories as given above

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.18.2/lib/File/Find.pm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use File::Find;

find(\&print_names, ('thisdir/one/', 'thatdir/two'));

sub print_names {
    my $name = $File::Find::name;
    print "$name\n"if $name =~ /\.(cpp|hpp|h|c)$/;
}
```

Comment: Yes, File::Find is cross platform.

Comment: Thanks for your comment--I edited the answer to remove the disclaimer that I hadn't tested it there so as not to introduce unnecessary doubt in any future reader.

Comment: You do not need the parentheses around your list of directories. Also, in the wanted subroutine you can use `$_`, so you do not need to check `$name`. E.g. `sub print_names { print "$File::Find::name\n" if /..../; }`

Comment: Hi msouth - In a full path list generated, only work around need to be done is, base directory is separated forward slash, where as file found from base directory is separated by backward slash.

Comment: I see--so would it be improved for me to put ('C:\foo\bar\',
'C:\foo\bar\barbar\') in for the directories?  (I'm hesitant to make that change without your confirmation because I don't have a system on which to test the code.)  Also, you might want to put the fact that you are asking how to do this on Windows, in perl, in the question title if it will still let you edit it (I'm a newbie here, I don't know).

Comment: @msouth: What the OP means is that the contents of `$File::Find::name` contains a mixture of backward and forward slashes.

Comment: Thanks @Borodin for the clarification and thanks for putting the sample code in as well.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a file path that uses mixed backward and forward slashes you need to use the [`File::Spec`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aSpec) module. The [`File::Spec::Functions`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aSpec%3a%3aFunctions) wrapper module just makes it slightly neater to call the functions it contains.

Try this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;
use File::Spec::Functions qw/canonpath/;

find(sub {
  print canonpath($File::Find::name), "\n" if -f and /\.[ch](?:pp)?$/;
}, qw{ C:\foo\bar\ C:\foo\bar\barbar });
```